# (VBScript) Read a text file and use the string value to search for directory

Tags: variables, vbscript, directory

I got a bunch of directories from external software program. The name always start from 1 and forwards depending on the number of the cycle in external program. Now, assuming that I have a text file (Test.txt) with one random number that I've calculated. My goal is to change to a directory that is already exist based on this string value and then plot a scatter diagram for the csv file inside this Folder. I wrote the following vbs script to automatically do this, but excel cannot find the file. Problem here is the parentfolder from Result.csv. How do I set the string value (MyVar) so that it can be used as path? Thank you.

```
StrFileName = "C:\Users\tanzil\Desktop\Test\Test.txt"

Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFile = ObjFso.OpenTextFile(StrFileName)
MyVar = ObjFile.ReadAll

Set ObjFso = Nothing
WScript.Echo MyVar
ObjFile.AddFromString MyVar
ObjFile.Close

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Source1 = "C:\Users\tanzil\Desktop\Test\"
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Source1 & MyVar &"\Result.csv") ' =====> Issue here
Set xlmodule = objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)

strCode = _
..........................
..........................
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
objExcel.Run "Evac_Curve"
Set xlmodule = Nothing
objExcel.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As

```
MyVar = ObjFile.ReadAll
```

reads **all** content from ObjFile, I suspect MyVar has a trailing EOL marker. Use

```
MyVar = ObjFile.ReadLine()
```

instead.